# How do I spawn a pop over view controller programatically?

Tags: ios, swift

My goal is to show a View Controller programmatically

Current View Controller

[image]

and then, if some event gets called or something, (API, or Websocket) I want to call these Views programmatically

[image]

But I want to call the last view Controller first and it is supposed to be on top of the first View controller

[image]

So technically the last View will have

```
Transition is Cross Dissolve
Presentation is Over Current Context
```

How would I do this?

Comment: use separate view (xib) and load where you need, remove then.

Comment: I prefer storyboard

Comment: this is for popover and use storyboard for the rest of the project.

Comment: You can use storyboard id and init the last controller where you will need it. `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
let myViewController 
= storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyStoryboardId") as? MyViewController`

Comment: @sinusGob you can also make a custom UIView with programming. Because as per your screenshot no more designing are there.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way for a reusable view is to create a xib file. Then you can create a singleton and call this view every time you want to show this modal view. 


To ensure that your view does not overlap with anything, you must add it not to the current controller, but to AppDelegate window.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window!.addSubview(yourModalView)
```

Answer (score 4):

As per your requirement, you can set a storyBoardID for your navigation controller.

On a particular event just instantiate the Navigation controller
`let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main) 
let myNavController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyStoryboardId") as? UINavigationController`

then present or show this navigation controller

`self.present(myNavController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

On `viewDidLoad()` method of first view controller perform the segue to popupViewController.

Now the secondView will show above the first view controller. you can dismiss this view after using it.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create the whole `UIViewController` for popups.

You can show a usual `UIView`. For example:

**Create view programmatically:**

```
let popupView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}
```

**Insert view when you need:**

```
private func showPopup() {
    view.addSubview(popupView)
    popupView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    popupView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    popupView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
    popupView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
}
```

**Also you can add views into your** `popupView`:

```
    let myLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Test text"
        label.backgroundColor = .red
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }

    private func setupPopup() {
        // add UILabel for example
        popupView.addSubview(myLabel)
        // Setup constraints for myLabel
        ....
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by overriding your `UIViewController` subclass' init methods, like this.

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        self.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    }

    // if this is a xib UIViewController, if not do not add this code
    required init() {
        // place the "SomeViewController's Nib Name" in the nibName to prevent crashes from iOS 8 devices
        super.init(nibName: "SomeViewController's Nib Name", bundle: nil)
    }
}
```

Then on your other `UIViewController`s you can initialize the said ViewController.

**xib and/or programatically**

```
// instantiate your UIViewController
let viewController = SomeViewController()
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**storyboard**

```
// instantiate the storyboard containing your UIViewController
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)

// place UIViewController initialization inside if let block to prevent unwanted crashes
if let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SomeViewController's Identifier") as? SomeViewController {
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Make sure your view hierarchy looks like this

[image]

This should be their properties

**View**

- backgroundColor = .clear

**Translucent Dark Background View**

- backgroundColor = .black
- alpha = 0.4

**Popover View**

.. whatever you want this to be